# High score code not saving scores properly

Tags: python, file-handling

I have this code as part of a larger dice game program to save the high score in a separate file (as well as the normal winning score file) but it always saves the highscore regardless whether it's higher or lower and also doesn't save it in the Winning_scores file either
It also saves it in the form of ('Name: ', 'John', 'Score: ', '10', '\n') instead of the variables separately because of the *str* because otherwise I get '*write() argument must be str, not tuple*' which I'm also not quite sure how to fix

```
tot1 = 5
tot2 = 1
name1 = ('John')
while True: #Code to find & print the winner
    if tot1 > tot2:
        print("Player 1 is the winner!")
        #Opens file & appends the winning score at the end of it
        tot1 = str(tot1)#Turns the score into a str
        win_score = open("Winning_scores.txt", "a")
        winner = ("Name: "+name1+" Score: "+tot1)
        win_score.write(winner)
        win_score.write("\n")
        win_score.close()
        print("Score saved.")
        hisc = open("Winning_scores.txt", "w+")
        highscore = hisc.read()
        highscore_in_no = (highscore)
        highscore_in_no = highscore_in_no
        if tot1 > highscore_in_no:
            print("Exceeded high score.")
            highscore_in_no = tot1
            hiscore = open("High_scores.txt", "a")
            winner = ("Name: ",name1,"Score: ",tot1,"\n")
            hiscore.write(winner)
            hiscore.close()
            print("High score saved.")
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your winner variable is a tuple, not a string.

in order to use `hiscore.write(winner)`, winner should be a string as follows:

```
winner = "Name: " + name1 + "Score: " + tot1 + "\n"
```

or nicer readable:

```
winner = "Name: {name1} Score: {tot1}\n".format(**locals())
```

you can also join your existing winner tuple to a string:

```
hiscore.write(' '.join(winner))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
winner = ("Name: "+name1+" Score: "+tot1)
win_score.write(winner)
```

When you wrap a value in parenthesis in Python, you're saying it's a *tuple*, something sort of similar to a list. Here's a hopefully more clear example

```
one = "foo"
two = "bar"
this_is_a_tuple = (one, two)
this_is_also_a_tuple = (one)
this_is_not_a_tuple = one + two
this_is_a_tuple = (one + two)
```